# Is there a shell initialization file that is run unconditionally?

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I want to know if there are any init or rc files that a shell will source/run on startup, regardless of whether the shell is *login*, *non-login*, *interactive*, or *non-interactive*. I don't see anything remotely like this in the manual pages for `bash`.

If not, is there a way to implement this myself *without* recompiling a shell to suit my needs?

(I'm primarily interested in answers for `sh` and its derivatives like `bash`, because I have never used `csh`.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic here, but this better fits in [\[ Unix & Linux \]](https://unix.stackexchange.com). So consider migrating this one to the same,

Comment: look for `/etc/profile`. There may be others. Good luck.

Comment: @sjsam, sorry about that. How can I migrate this myself? Can I?

Comment: `man bash`, then look for 'init-file'

Comment: use the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and select 'msg to moderator' (or similar). Ask for you Q to be moved as above. OR post this Q your self to `Unix & Linux` and then delete this version. Good luck.